# Want to create a sorting function that occurs upon clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, button

I want to add a high to low and low to high sort functionality in javascript that occurs when you click its respective button that I have already set up, I have the filter functions all figured out however I am stuck on the sorting. I have provided a picture of my current code.

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH7AQ.png)

[java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjZFM.png)

Comment: what are you trying to do?  if you have an Array of items, you might want to look at [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

            var sort_by_name = function(a, b) {
                var aJObj = $(a);
                var bJObj = $(b);

                return aJObj.find(".img_value")[0].value.localeCompare(bJObj.find(".img_value")[0].value);
            }
            $("#hightolow").click(function(){
                var list = $("#sort_group > div").get();
                list.sort(sort_by_name);
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    list[i].parentNode.appendChild(list[i]);
                }
            });
            $("#lowtohigh").click(function(){
                var list = $("#sort_group > div").get();
                list.reverse(sort_by_name);
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    list[i].parentNode.appendChild(list[i]);
                }
            });
    })

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="hightolow">hightolow</button>
    <button id="lowtohigh">lowtohigh</button>
    <div id="sort_group" class="sort_group">
        <div><img class="1" alt="1"><input class="img_value" hidden value="1"/></div>
        <div><img class="2" alt="2"><input class="img_value" hidden value="2"/></div>
        <div><img class="4" alt="4"><input class="img_value" hidden value="4"/></div>
        <div><img class="3" alt="3"><input class="img_value" hidden value="3"/></div>
        <div><img class="5" alt="5"><input class="img_value" hidden value="5"/></div>
        <div><img class="6" alt="6"><input class="img_value" hidden value="6"/></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```